# Convert system verilog packed array into unpacked array syntax using Python

Tags: python, system-verilog

I'm trying to convert below packed array lines inside a text file into unpacked one using python regex:

Here are the file contents:

```
inout [5:0]  IO_PMU_LED;

input [7:0]  PMU_DI_SCAN_IN_VCORE;
inout   [31:0]   PMU_DI_RIF_WR_DATA_VLP ;
output  [9:0]  PMU_DI_RIF_ADDR_VLP;
 input [5:0]  PMU_DI_LED_PAD_DRIVE_VALUE_VLP;
output   [5:0]  PMU_DI_LED_PAD_DRIVE_ENABLE_VLP;
```

Here is the desired output:

```
inout IO_PMU_LED [5:0];
input PMU_DI_SCAN_IN_VCORE [7:0];
inout PMU_DI_RIF_WR_DATA_VLP [31:0];
output PMU_DI_RIF_ADDR_VLP [9:0];
input PMU_DI_LED_PAD_DRIVE_VALUE_VLP [5:0];
output PMU_DI_LED_PAD_DRIVE_ENABLE_VLP [5:0];
```

Here is the code I have tried which is not matching any patterns inside the file:

```
with open ('input.txt', 'r' ) as f:
    print("Opening file:{}".format(f.name))
    content = f.read()
content_new = re.sub('^\s*(input|output|inout)\s+([\[\d:\d\]])\s+(\w+)\s*;', r'\1 \3 \2;', content, flags = re.M)
print("Finished replacing content")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is regex a requirement for this transformation? It seems like something you could whip up a parser for.

Comment: not a requirement but thought regex would be the easy solution?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to clean up the regex you were using:

`content_new = re.sub('^\s*(input|output|inout)\s+(\[\d+:\d+\])\s+(\w+)\s*;', ...)`

You had an extra set of brackets surrounding the content of the second capture group, which only matches a single character in the set. You also weren't handling more than one digit in the range statement, which meant the `[31:0]` declaration wasn't being captured.

EDIT:
I highly recommend [this online regex tester](https://regex101.com). It parses any regex you enter and tells you exactly how it will be evaluated.